# PHP +redirecting with sessions

Tags: php, session, redirect

i'm trying to make my site with a few languages. Every page includes config-file, wich checks variable 'lang' in session. If it doesn't exist, wi'll be redirected to the page of lang choosing. After choosing u'll come to the page before. But it works only in Mozilla Firefox. In other browser after language checking i always get this page (lang checking). What i did wrong?
Config-file:

```
// Here is session start...
if (!isset($_SESSION['site_lang']))
{
  $_SESSION['page_refer'] = "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=lang_choose.php">';
  exit;
}
else
{
  require_once 'languages/'.$lang.'.php';
}
?>
```

lang_choose.php:

```
// Session start
  @extract($_POST);
  if (isset($_POST['lang']))
  {
    $lang = $_POST['lang']; $lang = replace($lang);
    $_SESSION['site_lang'] = $lang;
    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL='.$_SESSION['page_refer'].'">';
  }
  else
  {
      // Showing form with flags... which returns var 'lang'
  }
```

---

**EDIT:**
If there is

```
< input type="image" src="img/langs/en.png" width="290" height="200" border="1" name="lang" value="en" />
```

in form it doesn't work in another browsers (except mozilla)
but if i use:

```
< input type="submit" name="lang" value="en" />
```

Everything is good. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't suppose this has to do with cookies being enabled/disabled? Sorry, I don't really know that much PHP, but this has bitten me before.

Comment: and don't forget, that i tested in 1 computer with another browsers. Only Firefox works normally. (in all browsers cookies are enabled)

Comment: Change the content attribute to wait 10 seconds instead of 0, then do a view source on the page to make sure the URL in the "URL=..." part is correct.

Comment: Hm, it's like script doesn't get lang-var...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using this to perform the redirect:

```
<?php
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
header('Location: ' . $_SESSION['page_refer']);
// And just in case that doesn't work
echo '<html>',
     '<head>',
     '<title>Redirect</title>',
     '</head>',
     '<body>',
     '<script type="text/javascript">',
     'window.location.href = "' . $_SESSION['page_refer'] . '";',
     '</script>',
     '<a href="' . $_SESSION['page_refer'] . '">Click here to continue</a>',
     '</body>',
     '</html>';
?>
```

Also note that use of the `<meta>` tag to redirect is [discouraged by the W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-CORE-TECHS/#auto-page-refresh).

Comment: I made some changes. Now it will also give a 302 header, then try to redirect using JavaScript, and finally display a link. If that doesn't work, maybe you should check your PHP error log, or add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` to the top of the file. Note that `ini_set()` will only work if there are no parsing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try a javascript redirect if setting the location header doesn't work:

```
echo '<script>window.location.href="',$_SESSION['page_refer'],'"</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do use header('location:'); based redirects make *sure* you add an exit() or die() afterwards, as the program will carry on running to the end, and some browsers may not even accept it, so it can fatally compromise security on occasions.